# Rails 3 + devise - email + user creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, authentication, devise

I am new to Rails. I am trying to create user management + login system using Devise. All is great except two things:

1) Is there any way to remove "email" field and/or validation when signing up? When remove :validatable from model, then passwords doesn't validate too.

2) What is best way to make user management in system? Something like overriding devise sign up?

I was searching in google for answers and readed documentation, but don't found answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should remove :validatable and write your own validation in User model.

2) You can create users by hand in devise:

```
@user = User.new(:field1 => "something", :field2 => "something else", :password => "secret", :password_confirmation => "secret")
@user.save
```

if created object passes validation it will be created just like with devise signup action.

Comment: 2) No, not role management, but user management. Creating users in applciation (manualy), not using devise "signup". Maybe there is some good tut for this? As I understand I need to hash passwords before inserting in DB.

Comment: edited answer according to your comment. you don't need to hash password yourself, devise will do that for you.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that. I tested in console your code and it makes password, but when I enter @user.save, it returns false. I will try - maybe it's my fault. Where can be found such a good documentation?

Comment: to check for validation errors type in console @user.errors, it will show you what went wrong

Comment: Thank you! All is great and working, but now I have another problem. I created UserController and in this controller is methods like: show, edit, new, update, etc. And when I use and click on `destroy_user_session_path` in the views, I got error - `Couldn't find User with ID=sign_out`. It seems like UsersController::show is invoked, how can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it! The problem was in routes.rb file `resources :users` needed to be below the `devise_for :users` route

Answer (score 1):

You can remove email validation with

```
  def email_required?
    false
  end
```

in your User model

Comment: Its not working. I have changed "authentication_keys" in config/initializers/devise.rb and added the above method as well. But still it is saying, email is mandatory. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't know from which version onwards, but at least at that time when you where asking your question, there was already a tutorial at the [devise github page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address) how to do it.
They outline two ways, one was described here, how to manage that. And you can keep their validations.

2) As for CRUD users they also have a [tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface) which is a bit more recent.

Hope this still helps someone ;-)